# 11street cURL API Error

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to add product to one of the marketplace (11street) via API. Everything seems right to be but it is not working. Can any expert point out the problem? :'(

Reference:
[image]

My Code: (URL: http://lazino.com.my/super/marketplace/11street.php)

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
//COOKIES
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
// Headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'openapikey:50667854bb253d281ce0fe36ebaeebaa';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.11street.my/rest/prodservices/product');

$fields_string = array(
'selMthdCd' => "01",
'dispCtgrNo' => "1",
'prdTypCd' => "01",
'prdNm' => "TEST product",
'prdStatCd' => "01",
'prdWght' => "0.1",
'minorSelCnYn' => "Y",
'prdImage01' => "http://staticfs.nexgan.com/images/logo/sallyfashion.com.my_new.jpg",
'selTermUseYn' => "N",
'selPrc' => "25.00",
'prdSelQty' => "0",
'asDetail' => "test",
'dlvMthCd' => "01",
'dlvCstInstBasiCd' => "11",
'rtngExchDetail' => "Test",
'suplDtyfrPrdClfCd' => "01"
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($fields_string));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "It's not working"?

Comment: It appears they want you to be sending XML and instead you're sending a `multipart/form-data` (since you pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`).  You need to build an XML string and send that instead of an array.

Comment: 11street is sure one hell api to work with